# How do you center a Google Maps InfoBox

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Per the example in the [documentation](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/infobox/docs/examples.html), they are centering the InfoBox with pixelOffset:

> "The pixelOffset is set to (-140, 0) so that the InfoBox is centered
>   appropriately."

```
pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
```

The problem is, my InfoBox is always changing content via `setContent()` and therefore always changing widths.

How should I center InfoBox above the marker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `boxStyle` width is 280px.

```
boxStyle: { 
          background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
          ,opacity: 0.75
          ,width: "280px"
         }
```

140px is half of that.  If the size of the InfoBox is dynamic you have to render it somewhere (where it will inherit the correct CSS), wait until it is rendered, retrieve the size, then set the pixelOffset to half of its width.

Comment: Wow that's so cumbersome, no wonder leaflet exists.  Your solution works pretty well though rendering the first one the div is really skinny.  I add a blank one to the map, then do setContent(content) then in the 'content_changed' listener I make the infobox visible.